# Run jar file in any os with RXTXcomm.jar and rxtxSerial.dll

Tags: java

I have a project to communicate with serial port communication which i build in eclipse. I created runnable jar and which is successfully running in mac by double click if i copy librxtxSerial.jnilib in library/java/Extensions.

But same runnable jar file I want to run in Windows too with double click not by command prompt.Please guide me what changes i have to do in my project and in Windows. Also I want the to know which is  correct rxtxSerial.dll is available on website.Thanks.

Comment: Please help me with this question.Jar file is running in windows and showing portName also but I think unable to read serial port

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help

The site below will help you get package you need.

https://github.com/jperezdiaz/6.141-Challenge/tree/master/lib/ch-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x64

You will require RXTXcomm.jar which you will reference in your libraries
and rxtxSerial.dll

I have also uploaded a project in github you can download the files.

https://github.com/mikemacharia39/JavaFX-Biometric

The code is in JavaFX but its similar.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I did it and bundled the jre with my project with the help of launch4j. Now I want to know can anybody see my Java code of my project through setup exe. If yes how can I prevent it. Is there any facility to give password or something . Thanks